# the box-shadow  'follows' the Jquery Slide Down effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-effects

I made this tiny video (please ignore if background noises)

http://www.screenr.com/Qvts

its 13 seconds but only need to see the animation going on in second 5; (or go [keepyourlinks.com](http://keepyourlinks.com) and wait few seconds untill you can se the same box and click)

The css -the item has both clases-

```
.keepeos .top {
    border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
    color: #000066;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 120%;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    right: 10%;
    top: -4px;
    width: 120%;
}

.caja_con_sombra {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

And the javascript (posted the full script but commented on the only, in my opinion, relevant line.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var variable;
        function check_more(id){

        var nID=$(".item_lista_links:first").attr("id"); //get the newest item's id
        var tid= nID.replace('link', '');
        $('#are_more').load('/includes/router.php?que=check_more&last='+tid+''); // check if newer
        }
          function buscar_nuevos(){
           var nID=$(".item_lista_links:first").attr("id");
           var id= nID.replace('link', '');
           variable = setInterval('check_more('+id+')',15000); //start checking
        }
        function ver_nuevos(id){  // when found news and retrieving 
           clearInterval(variable);  
            $('#are_more').html('');        //clear div


            /*THIS is basically the only relevant javascript line, i think */
            $('#load_more').slideUp(100).load('/includes/router.php?que=load_more&last='+id+'', 


function() {


    variable = setInterval("check_more(139125)",15000);
              $(this).slideDown(600); //start checking
                return false;
             });
        }
    </script>
```

So how can i prevent this shadow to expand the whole vertical animation?

Comment: Im sorry - i dont understand the problem - is the problem related to the username / password box that pops up on the website ? or the popup on the links that displays out of the screen ? or something entirely different ?

Comment: have you seen the video in the link?

Comment: Yes - you click on a link and some extra divs are added .... the problem is where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what's going on, but I know how to fix it (at least for now). It might be due to the element sliding in mixed with a height issue in jquery for elements that are children in the sliding element, but I'm not sure. Either way:

Knowing that, here is a fix. In **estilo.css** , find

```
.keepeos {
    height: auto;
}
```

Change that to:

```
.keepeos {
    height: 18px;
}
```

This will work against you if that ever becomes multi-lined, so if you need to in the future, maybe you can switch the tag while sliding and then switch it back when it's done.

Comment: nice! is not exaactly. it was .keepeos .top{height:23px} but you really gave me a clue where to look. thanks a lot!